# SerializeObject c# object with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json.net

when I trying to serialize to json an regular class that i read before all the properties in the json starts with $.

Why and how can I resolve it

Comment: Can you provide a json and code example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Be specific with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not have enough details, perhaps the below will help with going from a C# class to a JSON object and back.

First Create a class that mimics your JSON string (object) structure:

```
public class JSONobject
{        
    public Foo = new Foo();
}

public class Foo
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last {get;set;}
    public int ID {get;set;}
    ........
    ........
    public Bar = new Cover();
}

public class Bar
{
    public int ID{ get;set; }
    ........
}
```

Then, initialize the object as well as the serializer:

```
JSONobject jsonOb = new JSONobject();

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

Finally, parse the jsonString into your defined class:

```
try
{    
    jsonOb = serializer.Deserialize<JSONobject>(jsonString);

    //ViewBag.jsondecoded = "Yes";
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //ViewBag.jsonDecoded = "No" + ", Exception: " + e.Message.ToString();
}
```

The object now has all the data from your JSON object.
At last, you can do this backwards, just serialize the object:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonOb);
```